# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in recursive threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, recursion

I am creating an application for stress testing. to do this by 1500 and make 1500 threads simultaneously connections through an internal network on auditees. In 1500 turns is called a thread, each thread calls a socket when the socket closes this reopened and re-send the same data. The problem is that the application gives me errors saying that has infinite loops and stackoverflows are raised, but the idea is to create java recursive calls but does not leave me. What I can do?

Main class:

```
public void startStres(){

    for(int n = 1; n <= Integer.parseInt(valueThreads.getText().toString()); n++)
        robots.add(new robot(this, n, valueUrl.getText().toString()));

    valueTotal.setText(Integer.toString(robots.size()));

    for(final robot bot : robots)
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                bot.start();
            }
        }).start();
}
```

In Robot class:

```
public void start(){
        context.robotOnConnecting(idUnique);

        try {
            socketHandle = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(dataConnection.host), dataConnection.port);
            context.robotOnConnect(idUnique);

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socketHandle.getOutputStream());
            writer.print(
                "GET " + dataConnection.query + " HTTP/1.1\n" +
                "Host: " + dataConnection.host + "\n" +
                "User-Agent: " + dataConnection.userAgent + "\n" +
                "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\n" +
                "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\n" +
                "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\n" +
                "Connection: keep-alive\n\n"
            );
            writer.flush();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketHandle.getInputStream()));

            char[] bt = new char[1];
            br.read(bt, 0, 1);
            br.close();
            socketHandle.close();

            context.robotOnFinish(idUnique);
            context.robotOnClose(this, idUnique, true);
            //start(); <-- Error

        } catch (IOException e) {
            context.robotOnError(idUnique, e.getMessage());
            context.robotOnClose(this, idUnique, false);

            //start(); <-- Error
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
526-1073/com.x.audits.strestesting D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 16K, 21% free 50827K/63572K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
526-1095/com.x.audits.strestesting I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=25: stack overflow on call to Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal;.get:L
526-1095/com.x.audits.strestesting I/dalvikvm﹕ method requires 28+20+8=56 bytes, fp is 0x761f9314 (20 left)
526-1095/com.x.audits.strestesting I/dalvikvm﹕ expanding stack end (0x761f9300 to 0x761f9000)
526-1095/com.x.audits.strestesting I/dalvikvm﹕ Shrank stack (to 0x761f9300, curFrame is 0x761f9488)
526-1089/com.x.audits.strestesting I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=19: stack overflow on call to Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal;.get:L
526-1089/com.x.audits.strestesting I/dalvikvm﹕ method requires 28+20+8=56 bytes, fp is 0x76189314 (20 left)
526-1089/com.x.audits.strestesting I/dalvikvm﹕ expanding stack end (0x76189300 to 0x76189000)
526-1089/com.x.audits.strestesting I/dalvikvm﹕ Shrank stack (to 0x76189300, curFrame is 0x76189488)
526-1089/com.x.audits.strestesting W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=19: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418a8898)
526-1095/com.x.audits.strestesting W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=25: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418a8898)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with multi-threading, you should use a thread pool to avoid this kind of problem.

Check out [`ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Runnable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)). It will allow you to better handle your multi-threading.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: has completely solved my problem. This class can even handle my computer hardware, number of cores, etc and make it all work well :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
public void start() {
    while(true) {
        doWork();
    }
}

private void doWork() {
    // do all the work non recursively
}
```

Comment: It works but has the same problem last 30 seconds, just closes and shows the same logs.

Comment: Stackoverflow again??

Comment: I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 16400-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 0K, 19% free 106799K/131064K, paused 175ms, total 175ms
E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 16400-byte allocation.

Comment: So you have a different problem now. Your new problem is that you do not have enough memory to have that many threads allocating the necessary amount of memory. Yet my answer solved your recursion problem ;-)